# Weird problem on STM32 ADC with Interleaved Mode

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, adc

I am sampling a signal on STM32F3 Discovery board (stm32f303vct6) with two ADCs working in interleaved mode. It works great with a 200kHz 1V sine wave. But when I apply 10kHz 100mV sine wave, I see some interesting patterns. ADCs seem to convert all the voltage levels in a specific gap into a single number. It is like sampling in lower resolution. When you see the images below it will be clear.

I have also tried to run ADCs in independent mode and triggered them with 2 sycnhronized timers but still the pattern is there.
I don't encounter this problem when only one adc is sampling.

Images:

1 [Sampled signal with interleaved mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNH1q.png)

2 [Samples of one of the ADCs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjNsP.png)

Sample code:

```
#include "stm32f30x.h"
//#define DUALDMA

void sysinit();
void clockconfig();
void delay(int d);
void adcinit();
void dmainit();
void dualdmainit();

int main(){
    sysinit();
    clockconfig();

    #ifdef DUALDMA
    dualdmainit();
    #else
    dmainit();
    #endif

    adcinit();

    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOEEN; // GPIOE enable
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN; // GPIOA enable
    GPIOE->MODER = 0x55555555; // GPIOE -> output 
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x0000FFFF;// GPIOA -> analog

    // Reset SRAM memory area
    for(int i = 0;i<1024*4;i+=4){
        *((uint32_t*)(0x20000800+i)) = 0;
    }

    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;
    while(1);
}

void delay(int d){
    // Dummy delay
    int l = d*1000;
    for(int i = 0;i<l;i++);
}


void adcinit(){

    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_ADC12EN; // Enable ADC clock
    RCC->CFGR2 |= RCC_CFGR2_ADCPRE12_4;// ADC clock prescaler = 1


    ADC1->CFGR |=  ADC_CFGR_CONT; // Continous mode
    ADC1->SQR1  |= ADC_SQR1_SQ1_0 ; // ch 1

    ADC2->SQR1  |= ADC_SQR1_SQ1_0 ; // ch 1

    ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_DELAY_2 ; // Delay = 4 (5 Cycles)
    #ifndef DUALDMA
    ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_MDMA_1; // If single DMA is selected, configure MDMA bits for 12 bits
    #else
    ADC1->CFGR |=  ADC_CFGR_DMAEN;
    ADC2->CFGR |=  ADC_CFGR_DMAEN;
    #endif
    ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_MULTI_2 | ADC12_CCR_MULTI_1 | ADC12_CCR_MULTI_0; // Interleaved mode
    //ADC1_2->CCR |= ADC12_CCR_CKMODE_0; // Does not seem to change anything

    ADC1->CR &= ~(ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_1 | ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0); // Enable VREG
    ADC1->CR |=  ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0;
    delay(500);

    ADC2->CR &= ~(ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_1 | ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0);
    ADC2->CR |=  ADC_CR_ADVREGEN_0;
    delay(500);

    ADC2->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN;
    while( (ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRD) == 0 );
    while( (ADC2->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRD) == 0 );

}

void dmainit(){
    // DMA config for Single DMA, 32 bits
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN;

    DMA1_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)&ADC1_2->CDR;
    DMA1_Channel1->CMAR = 0x20000800;
    DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR = 1024;
    DMA1_Channel1->CCR = DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_1 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_1;

}

void dualdmainit(){
    // DMA config for DUAL DMA, 16bits
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN; // DMA1 Enable
    RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA2EN; // DMA2 Enable

    DMA1_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)&ADC1->DR;
    DMA1_Channel1->CMAR = 0x20000800;
    DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR = 1024;
    DMA1_Channel1->CCR = DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0;

    DMA2_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)&ADC2->DR;
    DMA2_Channel1->CMAR = 0x20000800+1024*2;
    DMA2_Channel1->CNDTR = 1024;
    DMA2_Channel1->CCR = DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0;

}

void clockconfig(){
    // External oscillator (HSE): 8MHz 
    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_HSEON; // Enable HSE
    while( (RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY) == 0 );

    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PLLMULL9; // PLL MUL = x9
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV2; // APB1 Prescaler = 2
    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC; // PLL source = HSE

    FLASH->ACR |= FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_1; // Two wait states

    RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLLON;  // Enable and wait PLL
    while( (RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0 );

    RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL; // Select PLL as system clock

}
void sysinit(){

    //STM32F303 reset state
    /* Reset the RCC clock configuration to the default reset state ------------*/
  /* Set HSION bit */
  RCC->CR |= 0x00000001U;
  /* Reset CFGR register */
  RCC->CFGR &= 0xF87FC00CU;
  /* Reset HSEON, CSSON and PLLON bits */
  RCC->CR &= 0xFEF6FFFFU;
  /* Reset HSEBYP bit */
  RCC->CR &= 0xFFFBFFFFU;
  /* Reset PLLSRC, PLLXTPRE, PLLMUL and USBPRE bits */
  RCC->CFGR &= 0xFF80FFFFU;
  /* Reset PREDIV1[3:0] bits */
  RCC->CFGR2 &= 0xFFFFFFF0U;
  /* Reset USARTSW[1:0], I2CSW and TIMs bits */
  RCC->CFGR3 &= 0xFF00FCCCU;
  /* Disable all interrupts */
  RCC->CIR = 0x00000000U;
  SCB->VTOR = 0x08000000; /* Vector Table Relocation in Internal FLASH */

}
```

Comment: What happens after you set the ADSTART bit? In the code you show here (which is a magic number mess btw) the processor leaves main. This is very unlikely for embedded systems of this size.

Comment: Questions, such as this, that are about the behavior of specific hardware -- especially peripherals -- are probably better directed to [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  You might get an answer here at SO, but we focus primarily on details of *programming*, not on the characteristics of hardware.

Comment: @Vinci sorry there was a while(1); at the end. ADSTART bit starts the ADC and ADC fills up the ram with the help of DMA. Those magic numbers are ram addresses which are not visible to the linker (the ones start with 0x2000)

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks i will try my chance there

Comment: How did you generate the plots? The code that reads the DMA buffer is not shown here as far as I can see, so we have to take it on trust that you are reading them appropriately.  I would expect code that processes the DMA data on the half and full transfer interrupts.

Comment: Have you confirmed the signal generator? It is generating what you really expect?

Comment: What is the resolution? 10KHz **100mV**. Try running the tests (10KHz 1V) and (200KHz 100mV).

Comment: @KuldeepSinghDhaka Yes i checked, signal generator is fine. Resolution is 12 bits. Here are the tests: [1V 10kHz](https://i.imgur.com/uNc7C5y.png) , [1V 200kHz](https://i.imgur.com/BYMJWya.png) , [100mV 200kHz](https://i.imgur.com/qDmZBA8.png)

Comment: @Clifford I read the samples through st-link. Save them as binary file and read it on another software.

Comment: @itlki - I believe that the two ADCs on the µC you use may (and will) have slightly different physical characteristics, which may be compensated using the internal reference voltage. In the dual ADC graph (no. 1), it looks as if the odd-indexed values resemble quite smoothly the sine curve while the even-indexed samples show considerable steps (or v.v., I don't know...). This may be a hint that one of the two ADCs has a problem with some fine-grained sampling components (capacitance etc.), while the other one is OK. This assumption is supported by the picture 2 ("Samples of one of the ADCs").

Comment: @itlki - I didn't notice an assignment to the sampling time configuration registers (ADCx_SMPR1/2), so the sampling time is configured to the minimum, 1.5 clock cycles (plus 12.5 cycles per conversion gives a sample every 14 clock cycles - using PLL system clock of 72MHz this corresponds to a sampling time of 20.83 ns and a sampling period of 194.44 ns). Sadly, I'm not experienced in analog electronics - please check yourself if this could be an issue at a certain signal frequency.

Comment: (to other readers -) The graphs provided have different abscissa scales.

Answer (score 0):

it looks your generator is a source of the problems. All your tests look consistent:

[image]

Find a decent oscilloscope and theck the generator.

Comment: What makes you sure it isn't the ADCs? I agree on the important finding that those "square" bumps are reproducted at the same voltage levels in various measurements. But what about the finding that the dual-ADC measurement has interleaved points with and without bumps?